# Trouble shooting a 404 in Rails production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I have a rails4 application that is deployed to production on an apache/phusion passenger stack.

There is an edit action for a nested resource in this application that is returning a 404. The route works just fine in development, even on my local system in production mode. I'm at my wits end to troubleshoot this, any input would be most appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I should have added that I've looked at the logs and haven't seen anything that shows what's causing the 404. Looked at the logs for both rails and apache and I can't seem to figure out what's going on.

Comment: What are the errors reflected in apache error.log and access.log, would like to see if the url is hit. what's coming up. Also i assume all other pages work fine